# Where is the F-4 Phantom II's flap lever?

Tags: cockpit, flaps, f-4

I'm trying to fly this fighter for the first time in X-Plane 11 but I can't seem to find the flap lever in the cockpit. Where is it on the real plane?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78711/discussion-on-question-by-jack-s-where-is-the-f-4-phantom-iis-flap-lever).

Answer (score 11):

[image]
([flickr.com](https://www.flickr.com/photos/59408786@N00/260068544/))

On a real F-4 it's the flap-shaped switch on the left console aft and left of the thrust levers. Also [here](http://aviation.watergeek.eu/images/f-4j/f-4j_block_22_front_1966.jpg) is the cockpit items poster (see item no. 5 on the left).

Comment: Unfortunately it's not there. I've added a photo to my question.

Comment: @JackS. - Unfortunately this site is not X-Plane support, asking where it is on the real aircraft is a more on-topic question. You'll need to check their support forums -- most likely it's mapped to two buttons without a visual representation in the virtual cockpit.

Comment: @JackS. - Kindly also check: [The scope of Flight Simulation questions on the Aviation SE](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/307/14897).